# Min/max month values with HTML range

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using a html slider with dates, specifically monthly dates.

The range input type does not play very well with non-integer values (though can be used also with decimal in a pinch). As such I am resorting to an array of values to populate the range.

However the actual range... of the range... is incorrect. I assume that a browser dependent fallback comes into play here. On Chrome it seems to default to 100. As there are 61 values, rather than 100, in the array that populates the range, the range breaks after the 61st value.

Ranges have min and max values that can in theory solve this issue. Min and max attributes for input of type month can take in values in the form YYYY-MM. However I seem to be unable to get values in this format to work in input of type range. The month input unfortunately has limited support outside of Chrome and does not provide the type of interface wanted for this application.

What recourse do I have to improve the range's behavior?

```js
var values = ["2010-1", "2010-2", "2010-3", "2010-4", "2010-5", "2010-6", "2010-7", "2010-8", "2010-9", "2010-10", "2010-11", "2010-12", "2011-1", "2011-2", "2011-3", "2011-4", "2011-5", "2011-6", "2011-7", "2011-8", "2011-9", "2011-10", "2011-11", "2011-12", "2012-1", "2012-2", "2012-3", "2012-4", "2012-5", "2012-6", "2012-7", "2012-8", "2012-9", "2012-10", "2012-11", "2012-12", "2013-1", "2013-2", "2013-3", "2013-4", "2013-5", "2013-6", "2013-7", "2013-8", "2013-9", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2013-12", "2014-1", "2014-2", "2014-3", "2014-4", "2014-5", "2014-6", "2014-7", "2014-8", "2014-9", "2014-10", "2014-11", "2014-12", "2015-1"];

var points = document.getElementById('points');
let rangevalue0 = document.getElementById('rangevalue0');
points.max = values[values.length - 1];
points.oninput = function() {
  rangevalue0.innerHTML = values[this.value];
};
```

```html
<input type="range" id="points" min="2010-01" max="2015-1" step="1" />
<br /><output id="rangevalue0">Select Date</output>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

points.max needs to be the index of the max value, not the max value itself. You're setting points.max to '2015-1', but try setting it to 60 instead:

```js
points.max = values.length - 1;
```

Comment: Beat me by a second :D

Comment: Btw that's setting it to 60 (which is correct), not 61. In addition, OP may want to remove `min`, `max`, and `step` from the `input`, as I don't think they're needed, or at least set `max` to `"60"`.

Comment: I had forgotten that I had left points.max in that code at all. I assumed that that property could not do what I hoped and did not bother even looking for a logical error!